# Sort list alphabetically by all columns in C# using linq (if possible)

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a list of cities with city name and city country and I want to use LinQ to sort by all the columns, matching a filter.

For example:

```
CITY_NAME    | CITY COUNTRY  
-------------+---------------
Buenos Aires | Argentina  
Asuncion     | Paraguay  
Sydney       | Australia  
Abadeh       | Iran  
Acero        | Bolivia
```

I want to get a list sorted by matching the .StartsWith the "A" letter but considering all the columns, but first City_Country and then City_Name, and also in alphabetical order.

The result should be:

```
Buenos Aires | Argentina  
Sydney       | Australia  
Abadeh       | Iran  
Acero        | Bolivia  
Asuncion     | Paraguay
```

This:

```
.OrderBy(city => city.CITY_COUNTRY).ThenBy(city => city.CITY_NAME)
```

doesn't work, since first order by country and after by name and I'll get a result like:

```
Buenos Aires | Argentina  
Sydney       | Australia  
Acero        | Bolivia  
Abadeh       | Iran  
Asuncion     | Paraguay
```

which is wrong, since **A**badeh | Iran matches better than  **A**cero | Bolivia.

I tried to be as clear as I could.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer (and I didn't test, so it's not fleshed out enough to be one), but it should move you in the right direction. `Cities.Select(city => new Tuple<string, City>(city.CITY_NAME)).Union(Cities.Select(city => new Tuple<string, City>(city.CITY_COUNTY)).OrderBy(item => item.Item1).Select(item => item.Item2).Distinct()`.  The `Distinct()` on the end is the sticking point, LINQ to Objects maintains order, other LINQ providers may not.

Comment: What does "matches better" mean? Both start with "A". What does "alphabetical order" mean? For which column or columns? Why did "Sydney,Australia" come before "Abadeh,Iran"? "Australia" should come after "Abadeh"?

Comment: If the city was Wellington in the country of New Zealand, where should it appear @RodriFerry ? Or should it not appear at all (since it doesn't start with A)?

Comment: Did any of those solutions work for you @RodriFerry ?

Answer (score 1):

I switched from lambda syntax to query comprehension to make it easier to cache the `StartsWith` results:

```
var ans = from city in Cities
          let countrysw = city.COUNTRY_NAME.StartsWith("A")
          let citysw = city.CITY_NAME.StartsWith("A")
          where countrysw || citysw
          orderby citysw,(countrysw ? city.COUNTRY_NAME : city.CITY_NAME)
          select city;
```

Basically you test the country and city for starts with matches, and sort those matches by country match first (false sorts before true) then by the matching name.

Comment: The OP says Country over City so I guess it would sort as "Australia" in the countries.

Comment: Why yes it would.

Comment: @mjwills I re-wrote the query to select/sort together properly.

Answer (score -1):

The `ThenBy` will only make any difference if you had two cities in the same country, since it sorts the countries, then sorts the cities *within those countries*.

For example, if you also had Perth, Australia in your list, then you would end up with:

```
Buenos Aires | Argentina
Perth | Australia
Sidney | Australia
Acero | Bolivia
Abadeh | Iran
Asuncion | Paraguay
```

If you want to sort by whichever of the city or country values comes first, then you could try something like this:

```
.OrderBy(city => string.Compare(city.CITY_COUNTRY, city.CITY_NAME) < 0 ? city.CITY_COUNTRY : city.CITY_NAME)
```

I think that will give you the list you expect.

Comment: Let's say the search was for the letter "B" rather than "A" (so the OP would want Buenos Aires as the first row in the results). Would this code do that?

Comment: Not exactly. My code only uses whichever value (city or country name) comes first in the alphabet. But it can be easily modified if you want to use a specific letter.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you need to project a new column that contains **either** `City` or `Country` (depending on whether it matches the `"A"` prefix or not) and then order by **that** new column. One possible approach would be something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class CountryAndCity
        {
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cities = new List<CountryAndCity>
            {
                new CountryAndCity() {Country = "Australia", City = "Sydney"},
                new CountryAndCity() {Country = "Argentina", City = "Buenos Aires"},
                new CountryAndCity() {Country = "Paraguay", City = "Asuncion"},
                new CountryAndCity() {Country = "Abadeh", City = "Iran"}
            };

            // The important bit starts here
            var results = cities
                .Where(z => z.Country.StartsWith("A") || z.City.StartsWith("A")) // this line is optional (only needed if you want to remove those that don't start with A
                .Select(z =>
                    new
                    {
                        OriginalData = z,
                        Match = z.Country.StartsWith("A") ? z.Country : z.City.StartsWith("A") ? z.City : "ZZZZZZ"
                    })
                .OrderBy(z => z.Match)
                .Select(z => z.OriginalData);
            // The important bit ends here

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", results.Select(z => $"{z.Country}-{z.City}")));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```